# Inductive limit of constant sheaves

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $U_n \subset U_{n+1}$ be an increasing sequence of open subsets of $X$. Let us note $U = \cup_n U_n.$

Do we have $$\varinjlim_{n \to + \infty} \mathbb{C}_{U_n} \simeq \mathbb{C}_U ?$$

Here is my try :

There is a well defined map $\mathbb{C}_{U_n} \to \mathbb{C}_{U}$ for all $n$, hence there is a morphism of sheaves $$\varinjlim_{n \to + \infty} \mathbb{C}_{U_n} \to \mathbb{C}_U.$$ Hence I can prove the iso on fibers. I thus have to prove that

$$\varinjlim_{n \to +\infty} \begin{cases} \mathbb{C}\,\,\, if \,\, x \in U_n \\ 0 \,\, else \end{cases} \simeq \begin{cases} \mathbb{C}\,\,\, if \,\, x \in U \\ 0 \,\, else \end{cases}.$$ This seems clear to me but I have a doubt.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my post.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{C}_U$ the sheaf associated to the presheaf which sends an open $V$ to $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $V \cap U \neq \varnothing$? Or do you need $V \subseteq U$ instead of $V \cap U \neq \varnothing$?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}_U$ is $j_! j^{-1} \mathbb{C}_X$ where $j : U \to X$ is the inclusion.

Comment: I think you can define an explicit inverse $\mathbb{C}_U \to {\varinjlim}_n \mathbb{C}_{U_n}$: for every open $V$, $\mathbb{C}_{U \cap V}$ is the set of continuous functions $U \cap V \to \mathbb{C}$ (with $\mathbb{C}$ given the discrete topology), which is non-trivial only when $U \cap V\neq \varnothing$. But then $U_k \cap V \neq \varnothing$ for some sufficiently large $k$. Thus every continuous map $U \cap V \to \mathbb{C}$ restricts to a cont's map $U_k \cap V \to \mathbb{C}$, which yields a map $\mathbb{C}_U(V) \to \mathbb{C}_{U_k}(V)$. You should still check it's well-defined and all.